# Azure cosmos dependency issue and AzureServiceBusMessagingAutoConfiguration$ServiceBusTemplateConfiguration NamespaceProperties not found

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect with Cosmos DB, but when only below dependcency given shown multiple error which got resolved after adding other dependency , but this case only with multi module project not standalone.

Standalone sufficent dependency
 `implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-cosmos:4.3.0'`

additional required for multi module spring boot project
` implementation "javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0.1"
implementation 'org.apache.qpid:qpid-jms-client:0.60.1'

```
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-messaging-azure-servicebus:4.3.0'
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-messaging-azure-eventhubs:4.3.0'

implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"

implementation "com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:4.3.0"`
```

Now after adding this, dependency error got resolved but while starting am getting below error.

Parameter 0 of method defaultServiceBusNamespaceProducerFactory in com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.servicebus.AzureServiceBusMessagingAutoConfiguration$ServiceBusTemplateConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.azure.spring.messaging.servicebus.core.properties.NamespaceProperties' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.azure.spring.messaging.servicebus.core.properties.NamespaceProperties' in your configuration.

I tried excluded AzureServiceBusMessagingAutoConfiguration.class and jms.servicebus properties with false match, nothing working not sure what wrong am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried excluded AzureServiceBusMessagingAutoConfiguration.class and jms.servicebus properties with false match, nothing working not sure what wrong am doing.

- Spring Boot is trying to configure a bean of type `NamespaceProperties` for Azure Service Bus, but it can't find the required configuration in your project.

I had configured some necessary properties in azure service bus.

[image]

**Application.properties:**

```
# Azure Service Bus configuration
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.connection-string=<Your-Service-Bus-Connection-String>
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.topic-prefix=<Topic-Prefix>
```

Add `Connection-String` with your actual Azure Service Bus connection string and `Topic-Prefix` with the desired topic prefix.

[image]

Additionally, If you want to `AzureServiceBusMessagingAutoConfiguration` and `jms.servicebus` properties please check the yml file

**Application.yml:**

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.servicebus.AzureServiceBusMessagingAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration
```

Here, I have connected my App insights to my `servicebus` that notify me when the messages triggered.

[image]

**In-detail:**

[image]